# Seeking alternative GUI File editor with large file support

Tags: editors, large-files

Can anyone recommend a file editor, preferably free, that handles large files as well as [EmEditor on Windows](http://www.emeditor.com/)? I'm on Ubuntu, but other people reading this might not be, so suggestions for other Unix operating systems are welcome, too.

Comment: I'm bumping this thread. Any more suggestions to choose from? Emacs appears to have O(n^2) or worse complexity when it comes to large files. Seek to the end and line insertion takes half a minute for files >500MB. I need an alternative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: What platform (machine, operating system, version(s)) is this for?

Comment: can you define size more accurately than "large" ?

Comment: @orion If you want to bump this 3 year old question, please edit it and specify your requirements. What's a large file for you? Does this still need to be GUI? What platform should it work on etc. By the way, I regularly use emacs to view large files. I just checked on a relatively small one (625M) and seeking to end took <1sec as did line insertion and whatever else. Saving took a few seconds (as in 5ish) but all else was responsive. That has always been my experience with emacs and I've used it for even larger files quite often. You might need to upgrade your emacs or hardware.

Comment: I could be of some help if you would tell me your OS and it's version.

Comment: While about Windows alternatives, [this question on Software Recommendations may have useful suggestions](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/785/1813) to search for.

Answer (score 8):

Just use `gvim`, it doesn't matter for large files, since the editor only reads limited lines to fill the screen, until you scroll down.

Comment: That's not correct. Vim loads the entire file in, and writes the entire file out on a save.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a link or source, @AlanShutko

Comment: That would be nice.  I can't find anything official, just lots of stuff referring to it, like http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Can-vim-view-VERY-large-files-w-o-having-to-load-entire-file-into-memory-td1186583.html.

Comment: @AlanShutko - I'm finding anecdotal evidence that it can edit large files (3-4GB) just fine. So I'm thinking that it can edit at least these largish sized files.

Comment: I'll have to try a 100GB file. 3-4GB isn't that big since most people have more memory than that.

Comment: Trying a 28GB file now.  With :set noswapfile and starting vim -u "NONE", opening the file has taken over nine minutes so far and virtual memory has grown from 2.7GB (on startup) to 15.36GB and continues to grow. It sure looks like it's loading in the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

In the unix environment there are two major editor you must consider:

- vim
- emacs

And for both there are plugins to improve very large files performance.

- for vim see "http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506"
- for emacs see "http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/vlf.el"

Give it a try, you won't be disappointed.

Regards,
Marco.

Comment: Of course, for both you have got GUI's.

Comment: Why was this down-voted?  Both tools handle large files very well.

Comment: vlf seems to be read-only. Which makes it no better than less.

Answer (score 2):

Another editor to take a look at is [hed](https://code.google.com/p/hed/).

*excerpt*

> Hed is a free hexadecimal editor for POSIX systems designed to efficiently handle infinitely large files in conjunction with operations like inserting in the middle of the file.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Very fast on very large files (keeps only necessary portion of the file in memory)
> - Fast inserting anywhere in the file
> - Fast saving of intermediate changes
> - vim-like controls (and exmode)
> - Powerful expressions concept for flexible searching and transformation operations on the file or a selected region

#### screenshot

[image: ss of hed]

Comment: This is a very nice tool, adding it to my personal toolset ;)

Answer (score 1):

[lfhex](http://stoopidsimple.com/lfhex) was written with this in mind. Despite the name, it can edit files in ASCII mode as well as hex.

> lfhex is an application for viewing and editing files in hex, octal,
>   binary, or ascii text. The main strength of lfhex is it's ability to
>   work with files much larger than system memory (or address space for
>   that matter!).

It uses a [paging abstraction](http://stoopidsimple.com/lfhex/manual/#Viewing) similar to EmEditor.

> lfhex can view files over 4gigs in size (if the OS supports large file
>   offsets). Using a paged i/o abstraction file open times are invariant
>   with file size, a 2gig file opens just as fast as a 2k file.

It's available in the Ubuntu repos, and probably other distros as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Unixland, the way to edit large files is mostly editing them as they stream by, e.g. with `sed(1)`. [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) provides a Unix-like environment under Windows, including `sed(1)`.

Comment: Oh god I didn't mean that :) I do use `sed` if I have a deterministic way of specifying exactly what to do. But sometimes I need an interactive editor for ASCII text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/uex.html) (commercial software, for-pay).
It can be [configured to handle large files](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html).

Comment: Did I just see a "buy now" for linux software? The end is near...

Comment: @orion There is commercial software on Linux, sometimes very expensive. For specialized programs (like, say, Mathematica), this makes sense. For an editor, a domain where the free software world has plenty to offer, it is a bit ridiculous to suggest a commercial solution, but I think that this product nevertheless does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that, despite OP specifically mentioning that he needs **GUI** editor, nobody suggested something like [CudaText](https://cudatext.github.io/), a **GUI** tool designed specifically for such purpose.

It opened my 100 MiB json file within a second, completed regex pattern replace within a dozen of seconds, while geany took several minutes just to open the file, and even vim crashed when I tried to perform this text replace.

[image]

(*Cudos* to [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/47929/41367))